# Architecture for MongoDB "relational" application

Tags: mongodb, nosql

This is the project, roughly: We have users and we have polls, users can both create polls or vote existing polls. Of course one user can vote just once each poll.

To me this is clearly relational, so in principle NoSQL makes no sense. But then I read a little and came to the conclusion that you can indeed make relations in MongoDB so I came to this scheme, I want to know if it is Mongo-ok or not before going on.

In a table/collection called users we store all the user data including an id (I guess default _id of mongo documents will be ok?)

In another table/collection called polls, we will have an id, the question, the possible answers and (here is where I start to have doubts) an array containing all the userIDs that had already voted? And then additionally the author's userID and also its username (I know this is duplicating but I read somewhere that I makes sense to do this in mongo, so that you don't have to launch another query just to know the user's username).

In MySQL I would have created a table with the voting relations (userID has voted pollID), but I guess in Mongo it makes sense to include this data in the poll document itself? Of course this array of userIDs will be constantly being updated, is that OK?

And what if I want to list all the polls created by a given userID? I know you can use find(), but is it as efficient as in MySQL at least for this case? Also each poll will be in a category and you would also must be able to sort by category and so, but I didn't wanted to complicate it further.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, one efficient way to go about this would be to have a `Users` collection in which you store all the data relating to your users, and then have a `Polls` collection that, as you mentioned, stores an array of `ObjectId` references back to your users.

This array can also contain some additional information such as a timestamp of when any given user has answered and the answer that was provided.

Still, be aware that it is not always a good practice to embed objects in an array, especially when it is unbounded (i.e.: the number of users will increase in time, thus making it possible for the references array on the Polls objects to also increase in time).

Nevertheless, I think that in your case this is a good approach to your application use case scenarios, especially since a user can only answer once to any given poll, thus limiting the rate of expansion of the array of objects.

Moreover, regarding your concern about querying the Polls collection by UserId, I think you will have no issue firing a `find` query as long as you properly index your collection. If you are only interested in retrieving the total number of polls created by a certain user without retrieving data about those polls, an alternative might be having a `counter` field defined on the user which would get incremented each time a user creates a poll.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have one doubt though, when you say: "to embed objects in an array" you mean just the userId integer or a "real object" type? I mean, the datatype would be an integer or an object? If the question makes any sense at all (which I don't think...), does it make any difference? And also: overall you think this kind of application could work better with Mongo than MySQL? (I guess this is more 'personal' but I would like to hear your opinion)

Comment: Exactly as you implied, when I say `object` I refer to an object data structure, as I assumed that you wanted to store more data about a user's vote than just the raw action. I think it all depends on your stack and the way you plan to use your data. Even if I am a MongoDB advocate, I think it all comes down to weighing the advantages and disadvantages of your particular application. It is quite impossible for me to recommend one or the other since I do not have all the information about your application. Nevertheless, both can perform really well if configured properly.